# GWT - how to set vertical scroll bar to left side?

Tags: html, css, gwt

I am just wondering... How to set vertical scroll bar from right to left side for ScrollPanel in pure GWT? Or maybe there is some alt walk-around?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just change a direction of scroll bar of scroll panel you can add following css rule to that panel

```
direction: rtl;
```

I tired this and it works. check out this code.

```
ScrollPanel scrollPanel = new ScrollPanel(new Label("I am just wondering... How to set vertical scroll bar from right to left side for ScrollPanel in pure GWT? Or maybe there is some alt walk-around?I am just wondering... How to set vertical scroll bar from right to left side for ScrollPanel in pure GWT? Or maybe there is some alt walk-around?I am just wondering... How to set vertical scroll bar from right to left side for ScrollPanel in pure GWT? Or maybe there is some alt walk-around?I am just wondering... How to set vertical scroll bar from right to left side for ScrollPanel in pure GWT? Or maybe there is some alt walk-around?I am just wondering... How to set vertical scroll bar from right to left side for ScrollPanel in pure GWT? Or maybe there is some alt walk-around?I am just wondering... How to set vertical scroll bar from right to left side for ScrollPanel in pure GWT? Or maybe there is some alt walk-around?I am just wondering... How to set vertical scroll bar from right to left side for ScrollPanel in pure GWT? Or maybe there is some alt walk-around?I am just wondering... How to set vertical scroll bar from right to left side for ScrollPanel in pure GWT? Or maybe there is some alt walk-around?I am just wondering... How to set vertical scroll bar from right to left side for ScrollPanel in pure GWT? Or maybe there is some alt walk-around?I am just wondering... How to set vertical scroll bar from right to left side for ScrollPanel in pure GWT? Or maybe there is some alt walk-around?I am just wondering... How to set vertical scroll bar from right to left side for ScrollPanel in pure GWT? Or maybe there is some alt walk-around?I am just wondering... How to set vertical scroll bar from right to left side for ScrollPanel in pure GWT? Or maybe there is some alt walk-around?I am just wondering... How to set vertical scroll bar from right to left side for ScrollPanel in pure GWT? Or maybe there is some alt walk-around?"));
    scrollPanel.setSize("100px", "100px");
    scrollPanel.setTitle("mypanel");
    scrollPanel.addStyleName("dit");
    RootPanel.get().add(scrollPanel);
```

and css class is like

```
.dit {
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: left !important; /*Only if you want to set text alignment to left.*/
}
```

( tested in chrome only.)

Comment: I tried to set this css style as setStyleName("ui-right-scroll"); but it makes ScrollPanel widget's text be aligned right but not replaces vertical scroll bar right itself :(

Comment: It's quite interesting think you. I tried the direction: rtl and it really replaced vertical scroll bar to left but all ScrollPanel content text became reflected or something as in a mirror :S But I just want to replace vertical scroll bar from its default right position to left one but not to reflect all its content :( How can I fix the total content reflection effect? Is there a way replace vertical scroll bar and NOT TO REFLECT all its content?

Comment: You have to dig into CSS more and should apply a seperete CSS for each and every element of CSS. there is no any absolute way to doing this. Best of luck. :-) Try to set inner content of scroll panel to direction:ltr !important; may helps you.

Comment: it is pretty interesting but I'd like to find some more complete solution. I guess there may be some easier way instead of manual settings of css attributes for each inner element :S I mean relocate vertical scroll bar 'to left' and keep all scroll pane elements directions untouched? It is quite hash to have left-sided-scroll-panel and to set its inner elements direction for all further gwt projects :( What do you think about a short walk-around? Can you suggest one?